# How to properly set Observable in the Activity to Pass data from API call in view model into Activity + Data Class for the list. Android Compose

Tags: android, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I think my observable is set incorrectly here. I am using Retrofit2 + Moshi as the deserializer, and the API call from Retrofit is working.

But once I make the API call, I am trying to set up the Observable in my Activity and then use the API call data from the data class.

Here is my view model code:

```
class DealsViewModel(val repository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {
  
  val movieList = MutableLiveData<List<DealItems>>()
  var job: Job? = null
  val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
  val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()
  val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
    onError("Exception handled: ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
  }
  
  fun getMovies()  {
    viewModelScope.launch{
      // View Model Scope gives the Coroutine that will be canceled when the ViewModel is cleared.
      job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler).launch {
        val items = repository.getProduct()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          if (items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            loading.value = false
            // put error message in here later
          } else {
            dealList.postValue(items)
            return@withContext
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  private fun onError(message: String) {
    errorMessage.value = message
    loading.value = false
  }
  
  override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    job?.cancel()
  }
}
```

And here is my MainActivity code.
I am using JetpackCompose in my activity, LiveData for the API response container. In my main repository is where I am validating a successful API response and then the coroutines for the call are inside of the view model.

My API call is successful, but I am not sure where to call the `ViewModel.GetMovies()` inside of the activity  and I am not sure if the observables are set properly and/or where to pass the API's livedata into my composable function.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am new to android and trying to use Coroutines for the first time.

```
class MainActivity: ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance()
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
    MyViewModelFactory(MainRepository(retrofitService = retrofitService))).get(DealsViewModel::class.java)
    // viewModel.getProducts()
    
    setContent {
      myApp {
        MyScreenContent()
      }
      
      viewModel.movieList.observe(
        this, { it ->
          if( it != null) {
            it.forEach {
              var movieLocation = it.movieLocation
              val description = it.description
              val id = it.id
              val title = it.title
              val regularPrice = it.regularPrice
            }
          }
        })
      return@setContent
    }

    viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, {
      Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })

    viewModel.loading.observe(
      this,
      Observer {
        if (it) {
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it always depends when should you call especially in the activity we have many lifecycles; however, the best way is to use the `.also` on the livedata/stateflow lazy creation so that you do guarantee as long as the view model is alive, the getMovies is called only one time, and also guarantee the service itself is not called unless someone is listening to it.
You may check the full documentation in this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Here is a code example

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<User>>().also {
        loadUsers()
    }
}

fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return users
}

private fun loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
}
```

}

When using this code, you do not have to call getMovies at all in the activity, you just listen to the observer.